# Free group $F(a,b)$ of rank 2 and free subgroup of rank $\infty$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Q: $F(a,b)$ is free group of rank 2, give an example (and proof it!) of free subgroup with infinity rank.

My attempt: I was trying with $G=[F(a,b), F(a,b)]$ and $G=\langle  {a^nb^n : n\in N}\rangle $

Both of these are subgroups of $F(a,b)$ (i can use the fact that first one is normal subgroup of $F(a,b)$, and second one is a group from it's definition).
Now I have a problem with showing that ${[a^n,b^m] : n,m\in N}$ is a set of free generators in first example, and $a^nb^n : n\in N$ in second example.
I saw many proofs of the first one but these were using too advanced stuff, I am new in group theory, don't know graphs and algebraic topology.

Comment: This is tricky to do in a completely elementary way. You don't necessarily have to find a free basis of the subgroup - it is enough to prove that it is not finitely generated. For your second example, let $G_k$ be the subgroup $\langle a^ib^i : 1 \le i \le k \rangle$ of $G$. Then it is sufficient to prove that $G_k \ne G$ for any $k$. You could do that by showing that reduced words in $G_k$ contain no powers $a^{\pm t}$, $b^{\pm t}$ of the generators with $t > k$.

Comment: In fact it is not too hard to prove this subgroup is free on the generators $a^nb^n$ (although you have to get the details right). The point is that you can get ancellation in adjacent terms in a word in these generators, such as $(a^3b^3)(b^{-5}a^{-5}) = a^3b^{-2}a^{-5}$, but the cancelling letter $b$ does not get eliminated completely, and after all cancellations of this type, the $b^{-2}$ will still have powers of $a$ to its left and right, so there can be no further cancellation.

Comment: I only dont understand one point. Why showing $G_k \neq G$ is sufficient?

Comment: It is not hard to prove that if $G$ was finitely generated, then we would have $G = G_k$ for all sufficiently large $k$.